# Pass multiple variables to PowerShell from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, pipeline

I'm invoking a PowerShell script from C#, I'm using a hashtable to pass through parameters however when it comes to invoking the PowerShell script I get

> *A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument*

The PowerShell script has two parameters.  The hashtable has two keys with one value each. PowerShell script below:

```
param([string]$username,[string]$path)
#Gets SID
$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount($username)
$strSID = $objUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
$SID = $strSID.Value
# delets user
net user $username /DELETE
# removes folder
rmdir /q $path
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\$SID"
```

C# that calls the PowerShell script:

```
class RunScript
{
    public static void FireScript(String script, Hashtable var)
    {
        RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
        Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
        runspace.Open();
        RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);

    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();

    String scriptfile = "..\\..\\Resources\\" + script + ".ps1";

    Command myCommand = new Command(scriptfile, false);

    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in var)
    {
        CommandParameter testParam = new CommandParameter(entry.Key.ToString(),entry.Value);

        //CommandParameter testParam = new CommandParameter(null, entry.Value);
        myCommand.Parameters.Add(testParam);
    }

    pipeline.Commands.Add(myCommand);
    Collection<PSObject> psObjects;
    psObjects = pipeline.Invoke();
    runspace.Close();
}
}
```

Code that calls firescript:

```
Hashtable var = new Hashtable();
var.Add("username","testb");
var.Add("path", "C:\\Documents and Settings\\testb");
RunScript.FireScript("remove user",var);
```

Comment: after more testing I have found that there sames to be a permission issue with removing another users directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need to set this parameter attribute: ValueFromPipeline which conform to [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714348%28VS.85%29.aspx) represents an 'Optional named parameter. True indicates that the cmdlet parameter takes its value from a pipeline object. Specify this keyword if the cmdlet accesses the complete object, not just a property of the object. The default is false.'

You can check also check [this link](http://tfl09.blogspot.ro/2009/01/parameter-attributes-in-powershell-v2.html) for some examples. The code could be like this:

```
param(
      [parameter(Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true)][string]$username
      [parameter(Position=1, ValueFromPipeline=$true)][string]$path
     )
```